# Does booting from a LiveCD damage my files?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, kali-linux, livecd

If I were to boot from my CD would it change my HDD OS or any data on my HDD?

I am asking because I have a desktop on Windows 7 but I want to be able to boot on to Linux temporarily so I can test it out. I want to keep everything of my Windows 7 and HDD, is this possible?

Comment: Questions on SU are expected to [show some research effort](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) on your part and should be included in your question please.

Answer (score 2):

Booting from the Live Disc alone will not install it on your computer.

**Unless you want to install it** to your computer **you have the option to launch the installer on the live disc.**

**You can Access your hard drive from the disc**. But this will not overwrite your settings and data unless you choose to do so.

**So It safe to say no it wont change any data on your HDD OS or any data on your HDD.**